# Ansible: run a failed task

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a playbook. My workflow looks like this:

- add a task or a few tasks
- run playbook
- if fails: change something and return to previous step

If the playbook is long enough it takes a lot of time rerun a playbook. Is there a way to run only the last(failed) task? or Can you propose the other way how to speed a process of playbook creation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use `--start-at-task` parameter of `ansible-playbook`

```
--start-at-task=START_AT
      start the playbook at the task matching this name
```

Another option is to use `--step` parameter that allows you to step through the playbook and decide what to run.